# R median inconsistent

Tags: r

Running the identical code on the identical data, using the identical function call, I find the R median function returning inconsistent results. Is this a bug in R or am I doing something wrong? Here are the data in question, along with the two distinct medians that were returned. The call to the median included na.rm=TRUE.

First run of program:

```
    epoch   x
    1       0.0280851454
    2       0.0277059423
    3       0.0252999465
    4       0.0291988163
    5       0.0291992778
    6       0.0318857602
    7       0.0351821603
    8       0.0356780765
    9       0.0383428958
    10      0.0383872088
    11      0.0343364561
    12      0.0306270197  <== median on this run
    13      NA
    14      NA
    15      NA
    16      NA
    17      NA
    18      NA
    19      NA
    Median  0.0306270197
```

Second run of program:

```
    epoch   x
    1       0.0280851454
    2       0.0277059423
    3       0.0252999465
    4       0.0291988163
    5       0.0291992778
    6       0.0318857602  <== median on this run
    7       0.0351821603
    8       0.0356780765
    9       0.0383428958
    10      0.0383872088
    11      0.0343364561
    12      0.0306270197
    13      NA
    14      NA
    15      NA
    16      NA
    17      NA
    18      NA
    19      NA
    Median  0.0318857602
```

Notice that while there are an odd number of data points, there are an even number of non-missing data points. With na.rm=TRUE the median should be the midpoint between the 6th and 7th data points (ordered by size). Instead, it appears that R is randomly selecting the 6th or 7th data point (ordered by size).

Comment: hi i am unable to replicate your post using `median(c(0.0280851454, 0.0277059423, 0.0252999465, 0.0291988163, 0.0291992778, 
    0.0318857602, 0.0351821603, 0.0356780765, 0.0383428958, 0.0383872088, 
    0.0343364561, 0.0306270197, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), na.rm=TRUE)`. can you share your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @chinsoon My program writes a csv file, and the results shown above are copied from the csv file and from a backup of the file. So sessionInfo() from my current session would not be helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: Could `x` actually be a factor? Then R is coercing the levels to integer and picking one. Try `median(as.numeric(as.matrix(data$x)))`.

Comment: @IanCampbell I'll take a look at that, Ian.

Comment: Copy-pasting your data and saving as CSV, I get the expected result _i.e._ `mean(c(0.03062702,0.03188576))` = 0.03125639. Converting column `x` to factor just throws an error when `median()` is used. I think something else is happening which is not reproducible from the information in your question.

Comment: It was a bug in my code :-(. I was re-using a matrix in a loop without re-initializing it. This meant that the median from a prior iteration of the loop was present when computing the new median. If the prior median was low this would force down the newly computed median, and if it was high it would force up the newly computed median. Thanks for your help, guys!